What are the comparative benefits of each kind of address
Of the available address formats: Legacy, Segwit, Native segwit and Taproot
Which is the better one in terms of security?
What are the benefits of using one address over the other?

I don’t think that there is a significant difference in terms of security between the various output types. Modern input types are more blockspace efficient, but a few wallets still cannot send to them.
P2PKH (aka Legacy)

Addresses start with 1…
All wallet software can parse the address format and send to it
148 bytes for an input, 34 bytes for an output

P2SH-P2WPKH (aka Wrapped Segwit)

Addresses start with 3…
All wallet software should be able to parse the address format and send to it
91 vbytes for an input, 32 bytes for an output

P2WPKH (aka Native Segwit (v0))

Addresses start with bc1q…
Almost all wallet software can parse the address format and send to it
68 vbytes for an input, 31 bytes for an output

P2TR (aka Taproot (aka Native Segwit v1))

Addresses start with bc1p…
Most wallet software can parse the address format and send to it, but a few services and wallets have not implemented support yet.
57.5 vbytes for an input, 43 bytes for an output

If you don’t mind occasionally dealing with a counterparty not being able to send to your standard addresses, I would just generally use P2TR. For more compatibility, use P2WPKH. I would be surprised if someone had a convincing reason to recommend Legacy or Wrapped Segwit today.

For better security and compatibility, using Native SegWit (bech32) is recommended for Bitcoin addresses. It offers lower fees and faster transaction processing. Taproot is more advanced, adding privacy and flexibility, but isn't as widely supported yet. Choose based on your needs and wallet compatibility!
